# IOS Universal APP center issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm Developing a iOS APP for 2 devices iPhone and iPad I am using 1 storyboard and thats the one for iPhone I also checked 'Use Auto layout'.

When I starts my app on the debugger on iPhone everything looks fine and nice when I start it on iPad 2, it also looks nice but my login screen is stick to left I put my form element inside the UIScrollView how do I center everything since iPad has a bigger screen size.

what I have tried:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2, 2);
```

but this looks very uggly and blurry.
so not worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make use of 2 storyboards i forgot to use of that im new to xcode 
problem SOLVED !